# Make a reverse filter

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a tableview and I want to filter the data to show only the cells witch has a different date than today, like a reverse search.

I have this to show the cells with a certain date:

```
filtered = events.filter({ (aEvent : Tareas) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = aEvent.eventStatus
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString("2016-11-24", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
```

I need to do the oposite, show the cells with a different date, is that posible?

Comment: Why not just `range.location == NSNotFound`?

Comment: it works, thanks!, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're massively overcomplicating this. There's no reason at all to be using Foundation data types here.

To keep events that **do** contain the desired date:

```
let desiredDate = "2016-11-24"
filtered = events.filter { $0.eventStatus.range(of: desiredDate) != nil }
```

To keep events that **don't** contain the desired date:

```
filtered = events.filter { $0.eventStatus.range(of: desiredDate) == nil }
```